# How to (un)hide lines within a legendgroup and access its lines individually

Tags: python, plotly, ggplotly

I created several lines with go.Scatter and grouped them with a legendgroup.
By clicking on the legendgroup I can hide / show all the lines.

What I would like to do as well is hiding / showing particular lines within a legendgroup.
Example 1 shows a legendgroup containing several lines that are initially hidden and some that are initially visible.
I would like to be able to change the visibility of all these lines individually but also be able to hide/show all lines (and their fillings) by just clicking once on the legendgroup.

```
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=datePrices, y=dfAreas.extendLow, mode='lines', name='extendLow',
                              line_color=LAVENDER, fill=None, visible="legendonly", legendgroup="AREA"))
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=datePrices, y=dfAreas.AREAHAlow, mode='lines', name='AREALow', 
                              line_color="rgb(255,0,255)", fill= None, fillcolor=AREA_FILL, legendgroup="AREA"))
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=datePrices, y=dfAreas.AREAHAclose, mode='lines', name='AREA',
                              line_color=AREA, fill=None, fillcolor=AREA_FILL, line_width=3, legendgroup="AREA")) 
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=datePrices, y=dfAreas.AREAHAhigh, mode='lines', name='AREAHigh',
                              line_color=AREA_UP, fill="tonexty", fillcolor=AREA_FILL, legendgroup="AREA"))                             
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=datePrices, y=dfAreas.extendHigh, mode='lines', name='extendHigh',
                              line_color=LAVENDER, fill="tonexty", visible="legendonly", legendgroup="AREA"))
```

Also I would like to group two legendgroups.
Example 2 shows a legendgroup containing two grouped lines for "Gains" and two grouped lines for "losses".
I can hide each of those two groups but I would also like to group these two groups making it possible to hide them with one click.

```
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=dfGainsOne.date, y=dfGainsOne.close, mode='lines', name='Gains', line_width=3,
                           line_color=colorGains, fill= None, legendgroup="Gains", showlegend=True)) 
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=dfGainsTwo.date, y=dfGainsTwo.close, mode='lines', name='GainsTwo', line_width=3,
                           line_color=colorGains, fill= None, legendgroup="Gains", showlegend=False)) 
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=dfLossesOne.date, y=dfLossesOne.close, mode='lines', name='Losses', line_width=3,
                           line_color=colorLosses, fill= None, legendgroup="Losses", showlegend=True)) 
traceList.append(go.Scatter(x=dfLossesTwo.date, y=dfLossesTwo.close, mode='lines', name='LossesTwo', line_width=3,
                           line_color=colorLosses, fill= None, legendgroup="Losses", showlegend=False))
```

If it would be adviced that it would be better to make this type of actions possible using some kind of popup window after clicking something that would be valuable to me as well if a link to an example could be provided.

Comment: I do not have reproducible data or current output, so I do not have a full understanding of your question. Are you referring to the recently introduced reference on [legend grouping](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#group-click-toggle-behavior)?

Comment: For the first part of the question, you can set the legend [`groupclick`](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#group-click-toggle-behavior) to `'toggleitem'`  so that clicking on an item toggles the visibility of the corresponding trace only. However, hiding all traces of the same group at once by clicking on the legend group itself is not implemented yet, see this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5911).

Comment: The issue mentioned describes exactly what I want. So it is not possible yet